# how to write xml back to a file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have about 100,000 price-table records in XML and I need to remove entries where the price amount is 0.00. The data is structured as follows:

```xml
<data>
    <price-table product-id="100109a">
        <amount quantity="1">10.00</amount>
    </price-table>
    <price-table product-id="201208c">
        <amount quantity="1">0.00</amount>
    </price-table>
</data>
```

I'm trying to use Python to do the work and I have the following:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

def readfile():
    with open('prices.xml') as f:
        contents = f.read()
        return(contents)

xml_string = readfile()

root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)

for price_table in root.findall('price-table'):
    amount = price_table.find('amount')
    if float(amount.text) != 0:
        root.remove(price_table)

xmltowrite = ET.tostring(root)
#print(xmltowrite)

with open('xmlwrite.txt', 'w') as j:
    j.write(xmltowrite)
```

When I run this, the error I get is:

> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

But my understanding is that the ET.tostring() function should be converting the xmltowrite value to a string... Why is that not a string at the end?

Comment: "I need to remove entries where the price amount is 0.00" - The code does the opposite of that.

Answer (score 2):

[`tostring()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring) returns a `bytes` object unless `encoding="unicode"` is used.

The code can be simplified quite a bit. There is no need to use `open()`, `fromstring()` or `tostring()`. Just parse the XML file into an `ElementTree` object, do your changes, and save using [`ElementTree.write()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write).

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("prices.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for price_table in root.findall('price-table'):
    amount = price_table.find('amount')
    if float(amount.text) != 0:
        root.remove(price_table)

tree.write('xmlwrite.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you print the `type(xmltowrite)` you will see it's a `<class 'bytes'>`. You can decode it with  `ET.tostring(root).decode("Utf-8")`, than you get `<class 'str'>`.